# Parser error that i am stuck with

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to read an excel file into the Ijupyer notebook with the following code :

import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib as plt

```
df=pd.read_csv('Data_2.xlsx')
```

However, it gave me the result : 
`ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 2`

[The excel file looks as such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV1sG.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you use [read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)?

Comment: Also, you have comma in your last column, which is a default separator.

Answer (score 0):

[read_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) solves it:

```
df=pd.read_excel('Data_2.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You're a life saver

Comment: @Matthew You are welcome.